# Air conditioning in my car works but takes a long time to cool...?

Tags: honda, ac, accord, leak, condenser

I have a '13 Accord that I've been having A/C issues with. I just worked on the car and vacuumed out the old refrigerant and filled with new (put the correct amount as specified by manufacturer). I checked both fans and they do turn on On hot days when it gets 90+,

I have to put it on full blast for at least 20+ minutes for it to become"tolerable". The car is silver with light grey interior. compressor works as it should, no leaks to be found and condenser doesn't seem to be clogged.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't put enough refrigerant into the system. Did you follow the weight guide since you vacuumed out the system? Also, have you checked to ensure your fans are working correctly? Does it work better when you're going down the road?

Comment: I should've added that in. Yes, I put the correct amount of refrigerant and both fans due come on. I did notice when I'm parked and rev it to 2k - 4k rpm it does get colder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the condensor is not clogged. Have you removed the cabin air filter and looked at the evaporator? If you have a shedding pet the cold side under the dash can get blocked with hair.
Also have you checked to make sure you are not drawing in outside air. Maybe a vent is not working properly.
As has already been suggested, maybe you are low on freon. I have a 1995 Toyota and live in south Florida. It took longer than I thought it should to cool down, so I added more freon using gauges. r134-a is best added by a scale, guages don't always give an accurate reading. I kept the low side below 40psi and after adding 1/2 a can the a/c began to blow cold within seconds, even in a car that bakes in the sun all day at work.

Comment: Before I vacuumed out the old Freon, I put about half of the 12 ounce cans and did make it much colder but after few minutes, compressor was kicking on and off every 5 secs and no cold air was coming out. Then I just went ahead and drew it all out and followed manufacturer recommendation

Comment: Sounds like a huge leak. You should have 30 to 40psi on the low side with the a/c running full blast. It should be a steady pressure. You need gauges to check this. With the car off for a long time, you will have about 100psi at the low side. When you run the engine and turn the a/c on, the pressure should not drop below 20psi. If it does you are out of freon and in this case it means you have a leak even if you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Honda CRV which is 19 years old, petrol engine.  About eight years ago my cooling system blew up as I put it on on a very hot day.  I had a new system and since then I find that the car cools much faster if you open all the windows immediately upon reaching the car, drive for a couple of kilometers and then turn on the air con and close the windows, the system is then much faster to cool the car!!! Driving a couple of kilometers with the windows down I do not find a problem, even if the air is hot, it cools the car which is hotter!  I would never start my cooling system again in a hot car without cooling it a little in this way first in case it blew again!

Comment: Or you could just take outside air using the Air conditioning. Gaz works.

Comment: wow, what happened exactly when it blew up? A loud boom? Did anything go flying, what did the explosion look/sound like?